# Ip to country, city, lat, lang javascript service

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, json, geolocation

What the best/accurate/free service to convert the IP from the following script to country/city/lat/long?

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
    function(data){
       alert( "Data Returned: " + data.ip);
  });
```

Comment: 10 answers and none accepted, nice stats.

Comment: A note of caution -- you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it goes I was researching this the other day.

Couple of potential options:

- [FreeGeoIP](http://freegeoip.appspot.com/)
- [IP Info DB](http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php)

Maxmind do a number of [APIs](http://www.maxmind.com/app/api) but their JS service doesn't look up to task to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend installing something locally on your server as it will make a huge difference in terms of speed.

This one is great: [MaxMind's GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location), and they have a free version with just a little less accuracy as the paid version.

You can download SQL tables or use a compiled C version with an Apache or PHP plugin.

[MaxMind GeoIP City](http://www.maxmind.com/app/city) or [MaxMind GeoIP Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/country)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a 3rd-party API, I prefer to have the data locally. You potentially trade off a bit of accuracy for less latency and a more robust application.

The best free database I have found is [IP address geolocation SQL database](https://ipinfodb.com/).