# get country name by ip adress in java

Tags: java

i want  to get the country name by give IPAdress in java.
e.g 192.168.0.1 . i want to get country name not host name. please solve this issue.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) Also, Java =/= JavaScript. Removing the JS tag.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on how to use things like MaxMind GeoIP Country out there. Also 192.168.0.0/16 is a private address block and won't resolve to a country.

Comment: please past the link here.

Comment: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite

Comment: You can refer to following two SO Questions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257170/how-to-get-city-name-based-on-ip-address-in-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374178/ip-to-country-city-lat-lang-javascript-service

Comment: Try this:http://www.lazylab.org/40/java/resolve-ip-to-country-name-in-java/

Answer (score 5):

There are many geolocation providers such as this free one:

http://freegeoip.net/static/index.html

This one allows up to 1000 lookups per hour for free.

If you access for example: http://freegeoip.net/json/124.168.50.23 to look up the address, you will find out that I'm in Australia:

`{"city": "Sydney", "region_code": "02", "region_name": "New South Wales", "areacode": "", "ip": "124.168.50.23", "zipcode": "", "longitude": 151.2055, "country_name": "Australia", "country_code": "AU", "metrocode": "", "latitude": -33.8615}`

Note that the example IP address you used (192.168.0.1) is from a reserved range (it's always on your local network), so you can't look up a country for it:

`{"city": "", "region_code": "", "region_name": "", "areacode": "", "ip": "192.168.0.1", "zipcode": "", "longitude": "", "country_name": "Reserved", "country_code": "RD", "metrocode": "", "latitude": ""}`

Comment: freegeoip now is free for 100 per month only